# Parameter 1 of function trunc() has type NUMERIC, but argument is of type java.sql.Date

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'easyloadController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service': Error creating bean with name 'easyloadService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'getRegularELSale': Error creating bean with name 'getRegularELSaleImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'easyloadCollectionRepository': Error creating bean with name 'easyloadCollectionRepository' defined in com.mmoney.airtimerecharge.modules.easyload.dao.EasyloadCollectionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract com.mmoney.airtimerecharge.modules.easyload.model.ELDailySummary com.mmoney.airtimerecharge.modules.easyload.dao.EasyloadCollectionRepository.getDailySummary(java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.mmoney.airtimerecharge.modules.easyload.model.ELDailySummary com.mmoney.airtimerecharge.modules.easyload.dao.EasyloadCollectionRepository.getDailySummary(java.lang.String)

JPQL query in repository
`@Query("select new com.mmoney.airtimerecharge.modules.easyload.model.ELDailySummary(COALESCE(SUM(e.amount), 0),COALESCE(SUM(e.robiCommAmount), 0),COALESCE(SUM(e.otfCommAmount), 0),COALESCE(SUM(e.gstoreCommAmount), 0)) from EasyloadCollection e WHERE e.status='S' AND TRUNC(e.txDate)=TRUNC(sysdate) AND e.msisdn=:mobile GROUP BY e.msisdn") ELDailySummary getDailySummary(@Param("mobile") String mobile);`

Entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "EASYLOAD_COLLECTION", schema = Config.DB_SCHEMA_EASYLOAD)
public class EasyloadCollection {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SLNO_GENERATOR", sequenceName = Config.DB_SCHEMA_EASYLOAD+".EASYLOAD_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SLNO_GENERATOR")
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SLNO_GENERATOR")
    private String slno;
    @Column(name="EXTREFNUM")
    private String extRefNum;
    @Column(name="REQTYPE")
    private String reqType;
    @Column(name="RESTYPE")
    private String resType;
    @Column(name="TX_DATE")
    private Date txDate;
    @Column(name="RESON")
    private Date resOn;
    @Column(name="MESSAGE")
    private String message;
    @Column(name="REQSTATUS")
    private String reqStatus;
    @Column(name="ROBITXNID")
    private Long robiTxnId; //number
    @Column(name="TXNSTATUS")
    private String txnStatus;
    @Column(name="ELTXNID")
    private String elTxnId;
    @Column(name="EXTNWCODE")
    private String extNwCode;
    @Column(name="MSISDN")
    private String msisdn;
    @Column(name="PIN")
    private String pin;
    @Column(name="LOGINID")
    private String loginId;
    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="EXTCODE")
    private String extCode;
    @Column(name="MSISDN2")
    private String msisdn2;
    @Column(name="AMOUNT")
    private String amount;
    @Column(name="LANGUAGE1")
    private String language1;
    @Column(name="LANGUAGE2")
    private String language2;
    @Column(name="SELECTOR")
    private String selector;
    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;
    @Column(name="OTFCOMM_TXNID")
    private String otfCommTxnId;
    @Column(name="OTFCOMM_AMOUNT",columnDefinition = "FLOAT")
    private double otfCommAmount; //binary double
    @Column(name="OTFCOMM_STATUS")
    private String otfCommStatus;
    @Column(name="CHANNEL")
    private String channel;
    @Column(name="GSTORECOMM_TXNID")
    private String gstoreCommTxnId;
    @Column(name="GSTORECOMM_AMOUNT",columnDefinition = "FLOAT")
    private double gstoreCommAmount;//binary double
    @Column(name="GSTORECOMM_STATUS")
    private String gstoreCommStatus;
//    @Column(name="GSTORECOMM_WALLET") //this column not in the database
//    private String gstoreCommwallet;
    @Column(name="C2CREQTYPE")
    private String c2cReqType;
    @Column(name="C2CRESTYPE")
    private String c2cResType;
    @Column(name="C2CRESON")
    private Date c2cResOn;
    @Column(name="C2CMESSAGE")
    private String c2cMessage;
    @Column(name="C2CREQSTATUS")
    private String c2cReqStatus;
    @Column(name="C2CTXNSTATUS")
    private String c2cTxnStatus;
    @Column(name="C2CELTXNID")
    private String c2cElTxnId;
    @Column(name="C2CROBITXNID")
    private int c2cRobiTxnId; //number
    @Column(name="C2CSTATUS")
    private String c2cStatus;
    @Column(name="C2CAGENT")
    private String c2cAgent;
    @Column(name="C2CDISTRIBUTOR")
    private String c2cDistributor;
    @Column(name="PRODUCTCODE")
    private String productCode;
    @Column(name="PRODUCTQTY",columnDefinition = "FLOAT")
    private double productQty; //binary double
    @Column(name="ROBICOMM_AMOUNT",columnDefinition = "FLOAT")
    private double robiCommAmount; //binary double
    @Column(name="ROBIERRORCODE")
    private String robiErrorCode;
    @Column(name="ROBIERRORMSG")
    private String robiErrorMsg;
}
```

database column

```
TX_DATE                     DATE
```

model class

```
@Getter
@Setter
//@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
public class ELDailySummary {
    private double daily_sales;
    private double daily_rc;
    private double daily_otf;
    private double daily_gcom;

    public ELDailySummary(double daily_sales,double daily_rc,double daily_otf,double daily_gcom){
        this.daily_sales=daily_sales;
        this.daily_rc=daily_rc;
        this.daily_otf=daily_otf;
        this.daily_gcom=daily_gcom;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.